Why is gradle transitive dependency version not being enforced?
I am creating a library which is built using com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks version 17.2.1, and its pom.xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-tasks</artifactId>
      <version>[17.2,17.3)</version>
    </dependency>
    ... other dependencies ...
  </dependencies>
</project>

My intention is that any app which uses this library uses a version of play-services-tasks between 17.2 (inclusive) and 17.3 (exclusive).  (I am not concerned with edge cases like 17.3-rc1 for now.)
However, when I build an app which uses this library, it uses play-services-tasks version 18.1.0.
The output from ./gradlew :app:dependencies includes the following:
+--- com.example.group:my-artifact:1.2.3
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[17.2,17.3) -> 18.1.0 (*)

so the play-services-tasks dependency is being promoted above the range I set.  No build errors are reported, and the APK analysis shows that version 18.1.0 is used.
What am I doing wrong?  Or have I misunderstood how transitive dependencies work, and it is not possible for a library to limit dependency versions in this way?
EDIT
The app's build.gradle.kts file is:
import com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfExtension
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

//noinspection GradleDependency
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("kotlin-allopen")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("com.google.firebase.appdistribution")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
}

private val isDevBuild = project.hasProperty("devBuild")

apply(plugin = "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf")

android {
    @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
    bundle {
        density.enableSplit = true
        abi.enableSplit = true
        language.enableSplit = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.appid"
        testApplicationId = "com.example.appid.test"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsCollectionEnabled"] = !isDevBuild
    }

    apply(from = "${project.property("signingConfigs.signing")}.gradle")
    apply(from = rootProject.file("buildscripts/flavors.gradle"))

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro", "proguard-rules-remove-logs.pro")
            testProguardFile("proguard-test-rules.pro")
            buildConfigField(type = "Boolean", name = "DEV", value = "false")

            firebaseAppDistribution {
                releaseNotes = project.findProperty("firebaseChangelog").toString()
                groups = project.findProperty("appDistributionGroup").toString()
                serviceCredentialsFile = System.getenv("FIREBASE_APPDISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIALS")
            }
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            signingConfig = null
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            buildConfigField(type = "Boolean", name = "DEV", value = "true")
            ext.set("enableCrashlytics", false)

            configure<FirebasePerfExtension> {
                setInstrumentationEnabled(false)
            }
        }
    }
    packaging {
        jniLibs.excludes.add("META-INF/**/*")
    }

    configurations.configureEach {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force(libs.android.test.monitor.get())
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.composeCompiler.get()
    }
    lint {
        abortOnError = false
        checkReleaseBuilds = false
    }
    namespace = "com.example.namespace"
    testNamespace = "com.example.namespace.test"

    @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            it.useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test::class.java).configureEach {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        events(TestLogEvent.STARTED, TestLogEvent.SKIPPED, TestLogEvent.PASSED, TestLogEvent.FAILED)
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

if (isDevBuild) {
    androidComponents {
        beforeVariants(selector().withBuildType("release")) { builder ->
            builder.enable = false
        }
    }
} else {
    apply(from = rootProject.file("buildscripts/google-play-publishing.gradle"))
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics)
    implementation(libs.firebase.performance)

    // Google AndroidX
    implementation(libs.google.material)
    implementation(libs.cardview)
    implementation(libs.webkit)
    implementation(libs.gridlayout)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.paging.ktx)
    implementation(libs.google.flexbox)
    implementation(libs.datastore.core)
    implementation(libs.datastore.preferences)

    // Google lifecycle
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.runtime.compose)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)

    // Google play services
    implementation(libs.gms.identity)
    implementation(libs.gms.ads)
    implementation(libs.gms.analytics)
    implementation(libs.gms.basement)
    implementation(libs.gms.maps)
    implementation(libs.gms.location)
    implementation(libs.gms.tasks)

    // Firebase
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.firebase.messaging)
    implementation(libs.firebase.analytics)
    implementation(libs.firebase.config)

    // Kotlin
    implementation(libs.kotlin.serialization.json)
    implementation(libs.retrofit.serialization) {
        exclude(group = "com.squareup.retrofit2", module = "retrofit")
        exclude(group = "com.squareup.okhttp3", module = "okhttp")
    }

    implementation(libs.example.myartifact)

    implementation(libs.google.play.appupdate)
    implementation(libs.espresso.idling)
    implementation(libs.okhttp.logging.interceptor)

    // Navigation
    implementation(libs.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.navigation.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.navigation.ui.ktx)

    implementation(libs.activity.compose)

    // Compose
    implementation(libs.compose.foundation)
    implementation(libs.compose.foundation.layout)
    implementation(libs.compose.material)
    implementation(libs.compose.runtime.livedata)
    implementation(libs.compose.ui)
    implementation(libs.compose.ui.util)
    implementation(libs.accompanist.permissions)
    debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.compose.runtime.tracing)
    implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
    debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.test.manifest)

    testImplementation(libs.junit5.api)
    testImplementation(libs.junit5.params)
    testRuntimeOnly(libs.junit5.engine)
    testImplementation(libs.test.hamcrest)
    testImplementation(libs.test.truth)
    testImplementation(libs.okhttp.mockserver)
    testImplementation(libs.retrofit.serialization) {
        exclude(group = "com.squareup.retrofit2", module = "retrofit")
        exclude(group = "com.squareup.okhttp3", module = "okhttp")
    }
    testImplementation(libs.test.core)
    testImplementation(libs.mockito.core)
    testImplementation(libs.mockito.kotlin)
    testImplementation(libs.coroutines.test)
    testImplementation(libs.mockk.core)
    testImplementation(libs.test.turbine)

    debugImplementation(libs.fragment.testing)
    testImplementation(libs.android.test.runner)
    testImplementation(libs.android.test.ext.junit)
    testImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    testImplementation(libs.espresso.contrib) {
        exclude(group = "org.checkerframework", module = "checker")
    }

    androidTestImplementation(libs.compose.material)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.compose.material.get3())
}

// must be at the bottom
apply(plugin = "com.google.gms.google-services")

Note: I get the same result if I remove this line:
implementation(libs.gms.tasks)
EDIT 2
Here is a part of the output from ./gradlew :app:dependencies which shows the `play-services-tasks dependency at the higher version:
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics -> 18.6.4
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.4.2 -> 20.4.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10 -> 1.9.23 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.3.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.1.0 (*)


Can you post your app gradle

@BobSmith I have edited the answer to include the app's build.gradle.kts.  Do have any ideas about what can cause the "hard" dependency version to be ignored?

can you also include output of command ./gradlew :app:dependencies ?

@BobSmith No, it's too big. What would you be looking for?  EDIT: I did include the section related to the library in the question.

What I am expecting is for the build to either use a version within the range [17.2,17.3) or for the build to fail because the hard dependency specified in the library conflicts with other hard dependencies.

I am looking forward to helping you. Without necessary details its not possible for me to do so.

OK, thank you for looking at the question. Without knowing what you are looking for I can't provide the relevant parts of the file.

There should be another part of the dependencies output which shows where the same dependency that is causing your problem (play-services-tasks) is selected by another dependency. ie, there is likely a dependency clash of some kind, so it would be informative to see what the conditions placed on that dependency are in the other location(s) it appears in your dependency tree

@SimonJacobs Yes, there are such dependencies which use play-services-tasks 18.1.0, but the point is that I would expect a build error if the hard dependency on version [17.2,17.3) cannot be met. I did not expect the hard dependency to be silently overridden by other versions of the same dependency.

We understand all that. I'm trying to tell you what information is being requested of you.

OK, if it helps I have included part of the dependencies output which includes play-services-tasks at a higher version.  I am sorry I can't add the full file because it's thousands of lines long and contains information I am unable to share. However, all the mentions of play-services-tasks are similar to the one I have added to the question.
